# std::vector throws std::out_of_range while reading tokens from a file

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a problem where I open a file (`tokens.tk`), I extract the tokens and put them into a `Tokens` struct. The problem I'm getting is when I'm trying to access the vector, it throws a `std::out_of_range` error. I don't know what is going on. Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef uint8_t u8;

struct Token {
  static const u8 UNSPEC{0};
  static const u8 NO_CHILD{1};
  static const u8 ONE_CHILD{2};
  static const u8 TWO_CHILD{3};
  static const u8 THREE_CHILD{4};
  static const u8 FOUR_CHILD{5};
  u8 level;
  string message;
  Token(u8 level, string message) {
    this->level = level;
    this->message = message;
  }
  static Token parse(string line) {
    string temp;
    istringstream iss(line);
    char lev;
    u8 tpe;
    iss >> temp >> lev;
    switch (lev) {
    case 'c':
      tpe = Token::UNSPEC;
    case '0':
      tpe = Token::NO_CHILD;
    case '1':
      tpe = Token::ONE_CHILD;
    case '2':
      tpe = Token::TWO_CHILD;
    case '3':
      tpe = Token::THREE_CHILD;
    case '4':
      tpe = Token::FOUR_CHILD;
    default:
      break;
    }
    return Token(tpe, temp);
  }
};

struct SortedTokens {
  vector<Token> first, second, third, fourth, none, unspec;
};

struct IOError {
  string message;
  IOError(string message, int line) {
    this->message = message;
    message.append(to_string(line));
  }
};

class TokenScraper {
  ifstream file;
  vector<Token> tokens;

public:
  TokenScraper(string filename);
  void parseFile();
  struct SortedTokens sort();
  ~TokenScraper();
};

TokenScraper::TokenScraper(string filename) {
  file.open(filename);
  if (!file.is_open() || file.peek() == file.eof()) {
    throw new IOError("Cannot open file at line:", __LINE__);
    file.close();
    return;
  }
}

void TokenScraper::parseFile() {
  std::string temp;
  while (getline(file, temp)) {
    Token t = Token::parse(temp);
    tokens.push_back(t);
  }
}

TokenScraper::~TokenScraper(){
  file.close();
}

struct SortedTokens TokenScraper::sort() {
  SortedTokens st;
  for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
    switch (tokens.at(i).level) {
    case Token::NO_CHILD:
      st.none.push_back(tokens.at(i));
    case Token::ONE_CHILD:
      st.first.push_back(tokens.at(i));
    case Token::TWO_CHILD:
      st.second.push_back(tokens.at(i));
    case Token::THREE_CHILD:
      st.third.push_back(tokens.at(i));
    case Token::FOUR_CHILD:
      st.fourth.push_back(tokens.at(i));
    case Token::UNSPEC:
      st.unspec.push_back(tokens.at(i));
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
  return st;
}

TokenScraper ts("tokens.tk");

int main(void){
  ts.parseFile();
  struct SortedTokens st = ts.sort();

  std::cout << st.first.at(0).message << '\n';
  std::cout << st.second.at(0).message << '\n';
  
}
```

And here is my `tokens.tk`:

```
@use 1;
@start 1;
@eval 2;
@end 0;
@include 1;
@def 2;
@alias 2;

pack C;
import 1;
export C;
```

the tokens have two parts:

1. the token (`std::string`)
2. the children(`unsigned char`)

I looked at other answers on StackOverflow and none of them really apply to me.

Comment: There's an empty line in your input. Think about what happens when you parse the empty string.

Comment: Always test for success after any IO transaction to make sure it was successful (or at least as successful as the stream can determine). `if (iss >> temp >> lev) { do stuff with temp and lev }` will trap a LOT of mistakes, and stuff you don't look for and trap usually turns into a bug you need to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of your problem is that *all* of your `case` blocks are missing a `break` statement.  So, no matter which value is detected by the `switch`, the code will flow into the corresponding `case` first *and then fall-through into all subsequent `case`s*.

As such, inside of `Token::parse()`, *most*<sup>1</sup> of your parsed tokens will end up being classified as `Token::FOUR_CHILD`, which means inside of `TokenScraper::sort()`, the `st.first` and `st.second` vectors are never populated, and `TokenScraper::sort()` will push the parsed tokens into the wrong `vector`s.

In `main()`, you are trying to access the 1st elements of `st.first` and `st.second`, which fails the bounds checks that you are performing with `at()`.

<sup>1</sup>: for the `pack C;` and `export C;` tokens, their `level` member will be *uninitialized* because `'C'` and `'c'` are not the same value, so your `case 'c'` block will never run. You should get rid of the `case 'c'` block altogether and move the assignment of `Token::UNSPEC` to the `default` block instead so that *all* unknown tokens get classified as `Token::UNSPEC`.

---

On a side note:

- in `Token::parse()`, you are not checking whether `iss >> temp >> lev;` is successful before using `temp` and `lev` later.  This is particularly important when handling the empty line between the `@alias 2;` and `pack C;` tokens.  You will end up with another `Token` that has an *uninitialized* `level` member.
- why are you using `at()` so much? Especially inside your `for` loop of `TokenScraper::sort()`, that is overkill since the loop is already doing the necessary bounds checking for you. So you can reduce some overhead by using `vector::operator[]` instead of `vector::at()` inside the loop.
- do not use `new` with `throw`.  You should be throwing the `IOError` object by value, not by pointer.  Although you can throw a `new`'d pointer, an exception handler that catches it will not `delete` it, thus leaking the object.

---

Try this instead:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef uint8_t u8;

struct IOError {
  string message;
  IOError(string message, int line) {
    this->message = message + to_string(line);
  }
};

struct Token {
  static const u8 UNSPEC{0};
  static const u8 NO_CHILD{1};
  static const u8 ONE_CHILD{2};
  static const u8 TWO_CHILD{3};
  static const u8 THREE_CHILD{4};
  static const u8 FOUR_CHILD{5};

  u8 level;
  string message;

  Token(u8 level, string message) {
    this->level = level;
    this->message = message;
  }

  static Token parse(const string &line) {
    istringstream iss(line);
    string temp;
    char lev;
    u8 tpe;

    if (!(iss >> temp >> lev)) {
        throw IOError("Cannot parse input at line:", __LINE__);
    }

    switch (lev) {
    case '0':
      tpe = Token::NO_CHILD;
      break;
    case '1':
      tpe = Token::ONE_CHILD;
      break;
    case '2':
      tpe = Token::TWO_CHILD;
      break;
    case '3':
      tpe = Token::THREE_CHILD;
      break;
    case '4':
      tpe = Token::FOUR_CHILD;
      break;
    default:
      tpe = Token::UNSPEC;
      break;
    }

    return Token(tpe, temp);
  }
};

struct SortedTokens {
  vector<Token> first, second, third, fourth, none, unspec;
};

class TokenScraper {
  ifstream file;
  vector<Token> tokens;

public:
  TokenScraper(const string &filename);
  void parseFile();
  SortedTokens sort();
  ~TokenScraper();
};

TokenScraper::TokenScraper(const string &filename) {
  file.open(filename);
  if (!file.is_open() || file.peek() == file.eof()) {
    throw IOError("Cannot open file at line:", __LINE__);
  }
}

void TokenScraper::parseFile() {
  std::string temp;
  while (getline(file, temp)) {
    if (!temp.empty()) {
      Token t = Token::parse(temp);
      tokens.push_back(t);
    }
  }
}

TokenScraper::~TokenScraper(){
  file.close();
}

SortedTokens TokenScraper::sort() {
  SortedTokens st;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i) {
    switch (tokens[i].level) {
    case Token::NO_CHILD:
      st.none.push_back(tokens[i]);
      break;
    case Token::ONE_CHILD:
      st.first.push_back(tokens[i]);
      break;
    case Token::TWO_CHILD:
      st.second.push_back(tokens[i]);
      break;
    case Token::THREE_CHILD:
      st.third.push_back(tokens[i]);
      break;
    case Token::FOUR_CHILD:
      st.fourth.push_back(tokens[i]);
      break;
    default:
      st.unspec.push_back(tokens[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
  return st;
}

int main() {
  TokenScraper ts("tokens.tk");
  ts.parseFile();
  SortedTokens st = ts.sort();

  std::cout << st.first.at(0).message << '\n';
  std::cout << st.second.at(0).message << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer because of the careful and precise analysis it includes. Great work!